# d3.js Dashboard inverting data on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I was using a Dashboard example from the d3.js website, [here](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/96447623ef4d342ee09b).

I modified it slightly to suit my needs, however, when I mouse hover, over the histogram, I see that the Low and High counts are inverted, that is, the count of Low becomes that of High, and vice versa.

[This](https://jsbin.com/decaladaju/edit?html,output) is a jsfiddle of the problem I am facing. As you can see, initially, the count of Low is 12, and that of High is 0. But upon mouse hover, over the blue histogram, the count of Low becomes 0, and that of High becomes 12.

Do you have an insights on why this is happening, and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the structure of your data between:

```
var freqData=[{"State":"apache-client-utils","freq":{"High":0,"Critical":0,"Low":12,"Medium":0}}];
```

And

```
 var tF = ['Low','Medium','High','Critical'].map(function(d){
        return {type:d, freq: d3.sum(fData.map(function(t){ return t.freq[d];}))};
    });
```

While I haven't looked too closely, changing freqData to:

```
    var freqData=[{"State":"apache-client-utils","freq":{"Low":12,"Medium":0,"High":0,"Critical":0}}];
```

will stop the inversion problem from what I can see.

Comment: The legend only updates the histogram value and percentage and not the type and its color. This is why it appears that the legend is inverting the data; it is not. It is only changing its order in half the legend while the other half remains the same. This is what your fiddle would look like if you updated the entire legend as you do the values: https://jsbin.com/keyibigucu/1/edit?html,output